# Accuracy does not increase in my ResNet on MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have built a ResNet model with `tensorflow` to classify MNIST digits. However, at training time, my accuracy does not change so much and stays around 0.1 even after 3-4 epochs, which corresponds to a random classifier (1 chance over 10 to make the right prediction).

I have tried changing activation functions (relu to sigmoid) but it does not improve the accuracy. Modifying the learning rate has no significant effect. I am wondering whether my get_variable() calls are correct....

Here is the full model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def conv_2D(x, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=None):
    '''
    2D convolution
    x: tensor of shape (batch, height, width, channel) -> 
    w: tensor of shape (f_width, f_height, channels_in, channels_out) -> weights
    b: tensor of shape (channels_out) -> biases
    '''
    # convolution
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding=padding)
    # add biases
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)

    if activation is not None:
        x = activation(x)

    return x

def print_tensor_shape(x, msg=''):
    print(msg, x.get_shape().as_list())


class RepBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, num_repeats, num_filters, bottleneck_size, name_scope):
        self.num_repeats = num_repeats
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        self.bottleneck_size = bottleneck_size
        self.name_scope = name_scope

    def apply_block(self, net):

        print_tensor_shape(net, 'entering apply_block')

        # loop over repeats
        for i_repeat in range(self.num_repeats):

            print_tensor_shape(net, 'layer %i' % i_repeat)

            # subsampling is performed by a convolution with stride=2, only
            # for the first convolution of the first repetition
            if i_repeat == 0:
                stride = 2
            else:
                stride = 1

            name = self.name_scope+'/%i/conv_in' % i_repeat
            with tf.variable_scope(name):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.bottleneck_size]))
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([self.bottleneck_size]))
                conv = conv_2D(net, w, b, stride=stride, padding='VALID', activation=tf.nn.relu)

            print_tensor_shape(conv, name)

            name = self.name_scope+'/%i/conv_bottleneck' % i_repeat    
            with tf.variable_scope(name):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([3, 3, conv.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.bottleneck_size]))
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([self.bottleneck_size]))
                conv = conv_2D(conv, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)

                print_tensor_shape(conv, name)

            name = self.name_scope+'/%i/conv_out' % i_repeat
            with tf.variable_scope(name):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, conv.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.num_filters]))
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([self.num_filters]))
                conv = conv_2D(conv, w, b, stride=1, padding='VALID', activation=None)
                print_tensor_shape(conv, name)

            if i_repeat == 0:
                net = conv + tf.nn.max_pool(net, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
            else:
                net = conv + net 

            net = tf.nn.relu(net)


        return net










def resnet(x):
    # reshape input
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    # init block for each layer
    layer_1 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=128, bottleneck_size=32, name_scope='layer_1')
    layer_2 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=256, bottleneck_size=64, name_scope='layer_2')
#    layer_3 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=512, bottleneck_size=128, name_scope='layer_3')
#    layer_4 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=1024, bottleneck_size=256, name_scope='layer_4') 

    layers = [layer_1, layer_2]

    # first layer
    name = 'conv_1'
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([7, 7, x.get_shape().as_list()[-1], 64]))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([64]))
        net = conv_2D(x, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)  

    print_tensor_shape(net)

    net = tf.nn.max_pool(
        net, [1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    print_tensor_shape(net)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv_2'):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], layers[0].num_filters]))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([layers[0].num_filters]))
        net = conv_2D(net, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)


    print_tensor_shape(net)


    for i_layer, layer in enumerate(layers):

        # pass the net through all blocks of the layer
        net = layer.apply_block(net)

        print_tensor_shape(net, 'After block')

        try:
            # upscale (depth) to the next block size
            next_block = layers[i_layer+1]
            with tf.variable_scope('upscale_%i' % i_layer):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], next_block.num_filters]))
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([next_block.num_filters]))
                net = conv_2D(net, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)

            print_tensor_shape(net)

        except IndexError:
            pass

    # apply average pooling
    net = tf.nn.avg_pool(net, ksize=[1, net.get_shape().as_list()[1], net.get_shape().as_list()[2], 1], 
                                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

    print_tensor_shape(net, msg='after average pooling')

    # fully connected layer
    with tf.variable_scope('fc'):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([256, 10]))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([10]))

    net = tf.reshape(net, shape=[-1, 256])
    net = tf.add(tf.matmul(net, w), b)

    print_tensor_shape(net, 'after fc')

    return net    



if __name__ == '__main__':

    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    Y_pred = resnet(X)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Y_pred, labels=Y))
    optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

    session = tf.InteractiveSession()
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    session.run(init_op)

    nb_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 128
    training_size = mnist.train.num_examples

    nb_mini_batches = training_size // batch_size

    # loop over epochs    
    for i_epoch in range(nb_epochs):

        # loop over mini-batches
        for i_batch in range(nb_mini_batches):

            # get mini-batch
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

            [_, cost_val, acc] = session.run([optim, cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y:batch_y})

            print('epoch %i - batch %i - cost=%f - accuracy=%f' % (i_epoch, i_batch, cost_val, acc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def conv_2D(x, w, b=None, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=None):
    '''
    2D convolution
    x: tensor of shape (batch, height, width, channel) ->
    w: tensor of shape (f_width, f_height, channels_in, channels_out) -> weights
    b: tensor of shape (channels_out) -> biases
    '''
    # convolution
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding=padding)
    # add biases
    if b is not None:
        x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)

    if activation is not None:
        x = activation(x)

    return x


def print_tensor_shape(x, msg=''):
    print(msg, x.get_shape().as_list())


class RepBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, num_repeats, num_filters, bottleneck_size, name_scope):
        self.num_repeats = num_repeats
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        self.bottleneck_size = bottleneck_size
        self.name_scope = name_scope

    def apply_block(self, net):

        print_tensor_shape(net, 'entering apply_block')

        # loop over repeats
        for i_repeat in range(self.num_repeats):

            print_tensor_shape(net, 'layer %i' % i_repeat)

            # subsampling is performed by a convolution with stride=2, only
            # for the first convolution of the first repetition
            if i_repeat == 0:
                stride = 2
            else:
                stride = 1

            name = self.name_scope+'/%i/conv_in' % i_repeat
            with tf.variable_scope(name):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.bottleneck_size],
                                    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[self.bottleneck_size]))
                # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.bottleneck_size]))
                # b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([self.bottleneck_size]))
                conv = conv_2D(net, w, b, stride=stride, padding='VALID', activation=tf.nn.relu)

            print_tensor_shape(conv, name)

            name = self.name_scope+'/%i/conv_bottleneck' % i_repeat
            with tf.variable_scope(name):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[3, 3, conv.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.bottleneck_size],
                                    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[self.bottleneck_size]))
                # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([3, 3, conv.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.bottleneck_size]))
                # b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([self.bottleneck_size]))
                conv = conv_2D(conv, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)

                print_tensor_shape(conv, name)

            name = self.name_scope+'/%i/conv_out' % i_repeat
            with tf.variable_scope(name):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[1, 1, conv.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.num_filters],
                                    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[self.num_filters]))
                # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, conv.get_shape().as_list()[-1], self.num_filters]))
                # b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.random_normal([self.num_filters]))
                conv = conv_2D(conv, w, b, stride=1, padding='VALID', activation=None)
                print_tensor_shape(conv, name)

            if i_repeat == 0:
                net = conv + tf.nn.max_pool(net, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
            else:
                net = conv + net

            net = tf.nn.relu(net)

        return net


def resnet(x):
    # reshape input
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    # init block for each layer
    layer_1 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=128, bottleneck_size=32, name_scope='layer_1')
    layer_2 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=256, bottleneck_size=64, name_scope='layer_2')
#    layer_3 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=512, bottleneck_size=128, name_scope='layer_3')
#    layer_4 = RepBlock(num_repeats=3, num_filters=1024, bottleneck_size=256, name_scope='layer_4')

    layers = [layer_1, layer_2]

    # first layer
    name = 'conv_1'
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[7, 7, x.get_shape().as_list()[-1], 64],
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
        # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([7, 7, x.get_shape().as_list()[-1], 64]))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64]))
        net = conv_2D(x, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)

    print_tensor_shape(net, name)

    net = tf.nn.max_pool(
        net, [1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    print_tensor_shape(net, 'After max pooling')

    with tf.variable_scope('conv_2'):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], layers[0].num_filters],
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
        # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], layers[0].num_filters]))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[layers[0].num_filters]))
        net = conv_2D(net, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)

    print_tensor_shape(net, 'conv_2')

    for i_layer, layer in enumerate(layers):
        print i_layer, layer

        # pass the net through all blocks of the layer
        net = layer.apply_block(net)

        print_tensor_shape(net, 'After block')

        try:
            # upscale (depth) to the next block size
            next_block = layers[i_layer+1]
            with tf.variable_scope('upscale_%i' % i_layer):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], next_block.num_filters],
                                    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
                # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([1, 1, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], next_block.num_filters]))
                b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[next_block.num_filters]))
                net = conv_2D(net, w, b, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu)

            print_tensor_shape(net)

        except IndexError:
            pass

    # apply average pooling
    net = tf.nn.avg_pool(net, ksize=[1, net.get_shape().as_list()[1], net.get_shape().as_list()[2], 1],
                                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

    print_tensor_shape(net, msg='after average pooling')

    # fully connected layer
    with tf.variable_scope('fc'):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[256, 10],
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
        # w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=tf.random_normal([256, 10]))
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]))

    net = tf.reshape(net, shape=[-1, 256])
    net = tf.add(tf.matmul(net, w), b)

    print_tensor_shape(net, 'after fc')

    return net

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    Y_pred = resnet(X)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Y_pred, labels=Y))
    optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

    session = tf.InteractiveSession()
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    session.run(init_op)

    nb_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 128
    training_size = mnist.train.num_examples

    nb_mini_batches = training_size // batch_size

    # loop over epochs
    for i_epoch in range(nb_epochs):

        # loop over mini-batches
        for i_batch in range(nb_mini_batches):

            # get mini-batch
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

            [_, cost_val, acc] = session.run([optim, cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y:batch_y})

            print('epoch %i - batch %i - cost=%f - accuracy=%f' % (i_epoch, i_batch, cost_val, acc))
```

The only problem is the initialization, both weights and biases. Note that there are other weight initialization methods, like

```
n = filter_size * filter_size * out_filters
kernel = tf.get_variable(
                '', [filter_size, filter_size, in_filters, out_filters], tf.float32,
                initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0/n))
                # initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
            )
```

Moreover, biases are initialized using constant 0.1 or 0.01 but in resnet, they do not use biases after conv2d in the block. Only use biases when using fully connected layers.

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem came from the `from __future__ import division` which was missing. I did not insert it in my other scripts neither but it yet worked. Don't know why it is required in this script.